# HTML adding user input values together into one value that is updated depending on the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not the best with html and I have not been able to find out how to do this from looking around on the internet, so I was hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

This is the code I have now :

```
        <p>
            <label for="food">Food</label>
            <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="food" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="auto">Auto</label>
            <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="auto" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="bills">Bills</label>
            <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="bills" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="monthlybudget">Monthly Budget</label>
            /* Add food + auto + bills whenever there is input */
        </p>
```

I am trying to add the user input of food, auto, and bills so that I can create a monthly budget depending on what there inputs were in the input fields. Each time a user inputs a value the monthly budget field will be updated but I cannot figure out how to do that.

For example:
Food: 200
auto: 150
bills: 400

Monthly budget $750

Comment: can you post the JavaScript code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it without jQuery:

```js
// When document elements have loaded:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Get reference to all inputs and output:
    var foodInput = document.getElementById('food');
    var autoInput = document.getElementById('auto');
    var billsInput = document.getElementById('bills');
    var budgetOutput = document.getElementById('monthlybudget');
    
    function calculateOutput() {
        // Convert input values to numbers (+) and put sum in output:
        budgetOutput.textContent = +foodInput.value + +autoInput.value + +billsInput.value;
    }
    
    // Calculate on any change in inputs:
    foodInput.oninput = calculateOutput;
    autoInput.oninput = calculateOutput;
    billsInput.oninput = calculateOutput;
    // Calculate at load:
    calculateOutput();
});
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="food">Food</label>
    <input type="number" id="food" />
</p>

<p>
    <label for="auto">Auto</label>
    <input type="number" id="auto" />
</p>

<p>
    <label for="bills">Bills</label>
    <input type="number" id="bills" />
</p>

<p>
    <div>Monthly Budget: <span id="monthlybudget"></span></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
var food=$('#food');
var auto=$('#auto');
var bills=$('#bills');
$('#food,#auto,#bills').change(function(){
 var total= getVal(food) +getVal(auto)+ getVal(bills);
 $('#lblTotal').text(total)
});

 function getVal(obj){
  return parseInt(obj.val()) || 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ysu05mfx/)

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<p>
        <label for="food">Food</label>
        <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="food" class="sourceinput" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="auto">Auto</label>
        <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="auto" class="sourceinput" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="bills">Bills</label>
        <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="bills" class="sourceinput" />
    </p>

<p>
    <label for="monthlybudget">Monthly Budget</label>
    <p id="monthlybudget"></p>
</p>
```

in your javascript file add:

```
$('.sourceinput').change(function() {
    $('#monthlybudget").text($('#food).val() + $('#auto).val() + $('#bills').val());
});
```

I am using jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Using `Number` to parse the input values

Check this  Fidddle https://jsfiddle.net/o44bke0a/

Answer (score -1):

Here I had attached the code for that using javascript.

Comment: The answer should be in the answer not in a comment. Can you edit your answer? Also, it is better to put the code also in the answer, not only the reference to it.

Comment: put link in the comments. also provide some code in the answer!!

Comment: Sorry for that I had included the url but unfortunately it fails to accept it that's why i posted it in comment.sorry for the inconvenience.